# How to execute a query when dropdownlist selected index changes

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, sqldatasource

I have a DropDownList which is populated using a sqldatasource, i.e., from database and their is a grid view which is populated with another sqldatasource connected to using the value of dropdownlist.

But it does not execute the query dynamically. I want that whenever the value of dropdownlist changes, the grid view should update. 
Code please..

Comment: Turn on `DropDownList.AutoPostBack` and see what happen?

Comment: And add the dropdownlist as a controlparameter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**ASPX code**

```
<asp:DropDownList id="ddlCountry" AutoPostBack="True" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlCountry_SelectedIndexChanged" ></asp:DropDownList>
```

**And CS code**

```
protected void ddlCountry_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  FillYourGridviewHere();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" 
        DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" DataTextField="ssn" DataValueField="ssn" 
         AutoPostBack=true>
    </asp:DropDownList>
```

This Worked. Thank You.!!

Answer (score -2):

You can just write the dynamic code for populating the grid into a function and bind that function to the dropdownlist onChange event.

Say "mydropdown" is the id of your dropdownlist  and "dochanges" is a function that executes your dynamic codes. So you just need to bind the dochanges function to the change event of your dropdownlist.

```
    $('#mydropown').bind('change',function(){
            dochanges(); //call the dynamic function where you update your grid
    });
```

Comment: Is not mention anywhere jQuery, and this code need jQuery library to work. And also in asp.net this can be done using the `OnSelectedIndexChanged` and the `AutoPostBack`. Also this id will not work, you need to use the `mydropdown.ClientID` ~

Comment: thankyou @Aristos .. I just mentioned an aliter way to do that in jQuery.

Comment: But the one in the question is not use it.